# Prism4: Creating catalog from xaml CreateFromXaml doesn't compile

Tags: silverlight-4.0, unity-container, prism-4

I'm developing with Silverlight 4 and Prism 4.

I'm also using Unity as my injection container.

I'm trying to create the module catalog from xaml, but I get this error "**IModuleCatalog does not contain a definition of CreateFromXaml**...".

My code snippet is:

```
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Practices.Prism.UnityExtensions;
using Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation;
using Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Modularity;
using Microsoft.Practices.Prism.MefExtensions;

namespace MyModularityProject {
    public class MyBootStrapper : UnityBootstrapper {
        protected override DependencyObject CreateShell() {
            return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<Shell>();
        }

        protected override void InitializeShell() {
            base.InitializeShell();
            Application.Current.RootVisual = (UIElement)Shell;
        }

        protected override IModuleCatalog CreateModuleCatalog() {
            // This is the isntruction that doesn't compile
            return ModuleCatalog.CreateFromXaml(new 
                Uri("/MyProject.Silverlight;component/ModulesCatalog.xaml",
                    UriKind.Relative));
        }
    }
}
```

What could I be missing here?

Comment: Did you try to clean your project. Close and reopen Visual Studio? The error talks about `*I*ModuleCatalog`. Thats the interface implemented by `ModuleCatalog` not the class itself. Any idea why this might be?

Comment: The answer is using a long qualified sentence:Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Modularity.ModuleCatalog.CreateFromXaml. Thank you

Comment: @user1462071 you should add an answer and accept it, instead of a comment

Answer (score 1):

The reason that you need to add the full path to the ModuleCatalog type is that there is a ModuleCatalog property within the Bootstrapper base class that UnityBootstrapper inherits.  If you don't qualify the name, you are essentially calling an accessor on a property which returns IModuleCatalog.  The interface definition does not include this function.